# how to convert a SystemColors to Brush?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a converter that return a Brush to set the background of a control in my view. However, when I return the SystemColors.XXX it does not work, however when I use a Brush then it works, so I am thinking that I need to convert the SystemColors to a Brush.

How can I do it? Because I have tried this:

```
return (Brush)System.Windows.SystemColors.HighlightTextBrush;
```

In the resources of the control I set this:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
```

I am using the transparent because the the background of the row I will set them by a multi value converter.

thank so much.

Comment: I see no reason that returning `SystemColors.HighlightTextBrush` should not work in your converter. But you have never posted the code where it gets called. Please post your code, here at SO we are pretty bad at reading peoples minds over TCP/IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own converter

```
public class ColorToSolidColorBrushValueConverter : IValueConverter {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            return new SolidColorBrush((Color)value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Declare it in the resource-section to use it.

```
<local:ColorToSolidColorBrushValueConverter  x:Key="ColorToSolidColorBrushValueConverter"/>
```

And the use it in the binding as a static resource.

```
Fill="{Binding Path=xyz,Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidColorBrush_ValueConverter}}"
```